# Usage of Groovy Closure in Groovy SQL

Tags: sql, groovy

I'm new in Groovy and kinda confused in using Groovy closures.

I'm inserting into a table while using Sql.execute(gstring, Closure)
and get this error

```
Caught: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect number of parameters for processResults Closure
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect number of parameters for processResults Closure
```

Here is my implementation:

```
sql.execute(insertPaymethodMethodByPaymentSourceId) { row ->
        println "$row.id"
    }
```

I'm using this function to use the new id for another function.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because there should be 2 params for this closure according to doc:

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#execute(groovy.lang.GString,groovy.lang.Closure)

processResults - a Closure which will be passed two parameters: either true plus a list of GroovyRowResult values derived from statement.getResultSet() or false plus the update count from statement.getUpdateCount(). The closure will be called for each result produced from executing the SQL.